# TypeError: 'list' object is not callable when web scraping to append lists/values to a column in csv file

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, python-requests

i'm having this TypeError: 'list' object is not callable in a for loop when calling functions that I defined earlier. I want to append/inject functions to my for loop to automatically populate the csv rows by columns

```
import requests
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import time
import csv

# copy and paste the url from indeed using your search term
URL = 'https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=data+science+summer+intern&l=New+York'

# conducting a request of the stated URL above:
page = requests.get(URL)

# specifying a desired format of “page” using the html parser - this allows python to read the various components of the page, rather than treating it as one long string.
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

# printing soup in a more structured tree format that makes for easier reading
print(soup.prettify())
```

This extract_job_title_from_result() function takes "job title" from indeed and append to "jobs" list.

```
def extract_job_title_from_result(soup): 
    jobs = []
    for div in soup.find_all(name='div', attrs={'class':'row'}):
        for a in div.find_all(name='a', attrs={'data-tn-element':'jobTitle'}):
            jobs.append(a['title'])
    return(jobs)

extract_job_title_from_result = extract_job_title_from_result(soup)
print('extract_job_title_from_result is: ', extract_job_title_from_result)
```

> output: extract_job_title_from_result is:  ['Data Engineer Summer Intern', 'Data Science Summer Intern', 'Data Scientist Summer Intern', 'Statistical Research and Data Science Intern', 'Data Scientist/Data Analytics Intern - Summer 2019', '2019 Summer Internship - Data Science Internship, Baseball Data', 'Data Science Summer 2019 Internship', 'Intern, Data Science', 'Data Science Intern (Social Media Analysis)', 'Data Science Intern']

```
# Set max result per city
max_results_per_city = 100
city_set = ['New+York','Chicago','San+Francisco', 'Austin', 'Seattle', 'Los+Angeles', 'Philadelphia', 'Dallas', 'Pittsburgh', 'Denver', 'Miami', 'Washington+DC','Jersey+City', 'Princeton']
columns = ['city', 'job_title', 'company_name', 'location', 'summary', 'salary']
sample_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = columns)
sample_df
```

> output for sample_df as column header but no data yet = city job_title company_name    location summary salary

Right now, I'm trying to web scrape and extract data from indeed. I've already written functions that worked and can use those functions to save/append into a column by column name in csv.

I want to scrape 100 results per city, and save/append those data in using the functions I've written to a csv file.

```
for city in city_set:
    for start in range(0, max_results_per_city, 10):
        #ensuring at least 1 second between page grabs
        time.sleep(1)
        #soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml', from_encoding='utf-8')
        sample_df['job_title'] = extract_job_title_from_result(soup)

        ### Ignore the below functions. They worked individually but not here in this for loop. I'm using a function to try to make it work first before appending all functions to csv by column name

        #extract_company_from_result(soup)
        #extract_location_from_result(soup)
        #extract_salary_from_result(soup)
        #extract_summary_from_result(soup)
        #sample_df.loc[num] = job_post

sample_df.to_csv('/Users/KingKong1/AnacondaProjects/testing1.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

I've gotten "TypeError: 'list' object is not callable" from `**sample_df['job_title'] = extract_job_title_from_result(soup)**`

Answer (score 2):

In `extract_job_title_from_result = extract_job_title_from_result(soup)`, you have replaced the function `extract_job_title_from_result` by its result, which is a list.

So, the next time you try to call it, `extract_job_title_from_result` isn't the name of the function anymore, but refers to this list.

Use a different name, for example:

```
job_title = extract_job_title_from_result(soup)
print('job_title is: ', job_title)
```